# Which UIView initiated UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikeyboard, uiresponder

Many of my views implement methods for a notification for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`

they move around internal views to move out of the way of the keyboard.

Problem I have is that I don't know which view triggered the notification.

How can I tell?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sender attached to the NSNotification object, if that's what you meant. You can use the **UITextViewDelegate** and **UITextViewDelegate** to store the sender globally, since the KeyboardWillShow notification is sent after the view becomes the responder(when editing begins, actually).

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        self.senderView= textField;
        // ...
}
```